# Add rows into a mysql table from a .sql file

Tags: mysql

I have a question on How I can insert a .sql file into a MySQL table which already contains lot of data ?

**My .sql file looks like (1200 rows) :**

```
--
-- Descriptif plan comptable SYSCOHADA (utf-8)
--

INSERT INTO llx_accounting_system (rowid, pcg_version, fk_pays, label, active) VALUES (10,'SYSCOHADA', 49, 'Plan comptable Ouest-Africain', 1);

INSERT INTO llx_accounting_account (rowid, fk_pcg_version, pcg_type, pcg_subtype, account_number, account_parent, label, active) VALUES (15000,'SYSCOHADA','CAPITAUX','XXXXXX','1',0,"Capital",'1');
INSERT INTO llx_accounting_account (rowid, fk_pcg_version, pcg_type, pcg_subtype, account_number, account_parent, label, active) VALUES (15001,'SYSCOHADA','CAPITAUX','XXXXXX','101',15000,"Capital social",'1');
INSERT INTO llx_accounting_account (rowid, fk_pcg_version, pcg_type, pcg_subtype, account_number, account_parent, label, active) VALUES (15002,'SYSCOHADA','CAPITAUX','XXXXXX','1011',15001,"Capital souscrit, non appele);
```

**My MySQL table looks like :**

```
mysql> describe llx_accounting_account ;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| rowid          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| entity         | int(11)      | NO   |     | 1                 |                             |
| datec          | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| tms            | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| fk_pcg_version | varchar(32)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| pcg_type       | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| pcg_subtype    | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| account_number | varchar(32)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| account_parent | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| label          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| fk_user_author | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| fk_user_modif  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| active         | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 1                 |                             |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My MySQL table is not empty. There is already data and I want to add my .sql file after my data table.

I didn't execute this command because I think it's false :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data_3.9.sql'
INTO TABLE llx_accounting_account
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Do you have the solution ?

Thank you :)

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Solution :**

With comments by @RakeshKumar and @PaulF, I found a way to solve my problem :

1) I deleted all rows where `fk_pcg_version = 'SYSCOHADA'`:

```
delete from llx_accounting_account where fk_pcg_version = 'SYSCOHADA' ;
```

2) I imported the .sql file :

```
mysql -u root -p****** dolibarr < data_3.9.sql
```

3) I modified one information because `account_number` was 1 instead of 10 where `rowid = 15000` :

```
UPDATE llx_accounting_account SET account_number = 10  WHERE rowid=15000 ;
```

Seems good :)

Thank you ;)

Comment: use cmd on mysql server like mysql -u username -p password dbname < filename
it will throw error if you already have rowid 15000, 15001, 15002, 10. If you want to avoid error and change rowid then use null instead og 15000, 15001, 15002, 10

Comment: @RakeshKumar Yes but in my database, I have 57 tables. So how I can specify to import my .sql file on the table `llx_accounting_account` and not `llx_accounting_system` for example ?

Comment: your query already have table name

INSERT INTO llx_accounting_system (rowid, pcg_version, fk_pays, label, active) VALUES (10,'SYSCOHADA', 49, 'Plan comptable Ouest-Africain', 1);

Comment: you have to search and replace your .sql file content.

Comment: @RakeshKumar Ok, I made `mysql -u root -p ***** dolibarr < data_3.9.sql` and I get : `ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 5: Duplicate entry '10' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: so you already have row id 10,  in this query INSERT INTO llx_accounting_system (rowid, pcg_version, fk_pays, label, active) VALUES (10,'SYSCOHADA', 49, 'Plan comptable Ouest-Africain', 1);
 do yopu want to use rowid 10 or not

Comment: @RakeshKumar No it's not a problem if the `rowid` is different. My MySQL table is not empty, so `rowid = 10` is already used by an other accounting plan

Comment: ok so open ur sql file and replace rowid 15000, 15001, 15002, 10 with null value

Comment: It looks like you may need to do a lot of work editing that file if you change the rowid value in the llx_accounting_account table as Rakesh suggests - as the account_parent field will need modifying to match.

Comment: @Andromedae93 is it worked for you?

Comment: @RakeshKumar Yes, I edited my question and I posted my solution step by step ;) Thank you !

Comment: ok, i also created a answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following way to import file

```
mysql -u username -p'password' dbname < filename.sql
```

Your import didn't work because you had already your same old `SYSCOHADA` rows in your table.

You can delete all rows where `fk_pcg_version = 'SYSCOHADA'` and import again your file corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error importing data from a SQL file that was created from a mysqldump table output to file command. The reason was that the SQL file has the DROP TABLE IF EXISTS and CREATE TABLE statement at the start of the file.
Once this is removed, then it effectively appends the rows to the existing records.
Maybe this will help others.

Comment: Very simple. The main question is "Add rows into a mysql table from a .sql file" and in the user's request is mentioned "My MySQL table is not empty. There is already data and I want to add my .sql file after my data table.". I was searching for an answer to my own problem which was sovled from my above answer. I agree the it does not follow exactly the problem described, however it could be a solution for someone else searching for an answer based on the immediate question title. If you don't like it, feel free to delete my answer. I only put it in to help someone solving a problem.